# python exception handling order

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to handle an exception in order,
if the first exeption dosn't work it should run the second one, but in code if the 1st exception dosn't work it stop running

```
try:
            
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(Newtweet_button).click()           #tweet button 
        sleep(2)
        
    
    except (ElementClickInterceptedException):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(cross_button).click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(close_button2).click()            #if tweet is repeated 
        sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(Newtweet_button).click()          
        
    except (ElementClickInterceptedException):
        sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(Newtweet_button).click()           #tweet button 
        sleep(2)
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that the  condition for both the except statements is the same.
When an exception occurs in the try suite, a search for an exception handler is started. This search inspects the except clauses in turn until one is found that matches the exception.

Comment: so what I can I do ? can combine 2 exeption togather ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but it seems like you want perform two different actions for  the same exception. One of the except statements should have different condition for which it is triggered.

Comment: how can I create a general exeption ?

Answer (score 0):

you `cant` `except` this `ElementClickInterceptedException` or `any exception` multiple times in the same `try/except` block.

you `CANT` do this:

```
try:
    # stuff
except (ElementClickInterceptedException):
    # stuff
except (ElementClickInterceptedException):
    # stuff
```

instead you can use this method:

```
try:
    # stuff
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    try:
        # stuff
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        # stuff
```

(btw, parentheses are `redundant` in python in `such situations`, `loops condition` and `conditions`)

or this method (infinite loop that tries to find the element):

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(Newtweet_button).click()

        # if the above works, then quit the exception block
        break

    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        # except and try again
        pass
    
    # and you can sleep here to slow the process
    sleep(2)
```

honestly, i used this method with `while True` a lot of times, because its the best when trying to find a `webelement` that is not loaded yet.

of course, you can put a condition to stop the infinite searching when iterates more than a `limit` set by you.